# How to navigate from one activity to another activity to specific fragment in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using `BottomNavigationView` with NavController in Activity A. I want to return back to specific fragment in Activity A from Activity B. How to perform in Kotlin ?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation Component has something called [Global Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) that should do what you are looking for